# Does creating a new File instance cause creating an empty file?

Tags: java, file

I read the `File` class [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-). Here is what's written there:

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string,
>   then the result is the empty abstract pathname.

**QUESTION**: Is it guarantee that if file doesn't exist it won't create an empty file or it depends on the system? I tried it on RedHat linux and an empty file is created only after I create `OutputStream`.

It's not obvious from java to me.

Comment: A `File` instance is just a handle to the file itself. As long as you don't write to that file or call `createNewFile()` etc. on it nothing is being created if it doesn't already exist. Besides that, the JavaDoc excerpt you provided doesn't say anything about that topic but refers to path names only.

Comment: Think of the `File` object as an abstraction of the file name. No action will be carried out on the file system.

Comment: A `File` is a wrapper for a `String` which offers some file checking methods like `File.exists()` which would do very much if it always actually create a file.

Comment: The only "guarantee" I found is that the constructors doesn't throws IOException, exception needed in case of Access issues. This is a bit light but that's a start ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed that the file won't be created by calling `new File()`. It'll be created if you call `createNewFile()`.

The pattern might be:

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // do something
} else {
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: I agree about the createNewFile() method. But if you *guarantee* certain behavior you might want add some link / source to back that claim!

Comment: The only "guarantee" I found is that the constructors doesn't throws IOException, exception needed in case of Access issues. This is a bit light but that's a start ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the source code in the constructor, you see that creating a new File instance just initialises some internal variables:

```
public File(String pathname) {
    if (pathname == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
    this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```

So just creating a new File object will not result in a new file being created.